How can I reattach loose wooden stair treads?
These three wooden steps are in the vestibule leading up to a home. The second tread had some play when you stepped on it. I cut pieces of wood to wedge in there. This stabilized the second step, but now the bottom step has similar play when you step on it. I’m looking for temporary fixes while I figure out something permanent. Appreciate any input, thanks.





At first I thought your treads were entrapped by the side skirts, so that good repairs would require removing at least one of them. That doesn't seem to be the case on the right side. This means you can take the treads off with little effort and see what's what.
That's the first step with any project like this. Get a look at it. We don't know if there's rotten wood, corroded fasteners, or what. Start there.
Then it's a matter of replacing what needs replacing, and making improvements where you can.

If the stringers are rotted, replace them or add blocking, etc., to support weak areas.

If screws or nails are rusted away, pull the remnants and replace them with fresh, corrosion-resistant screws in solid wood.

Consider using construction adhesive at all points of contact to support and reduce movement and noise.


Also consider doing any sanding and refinishing while things are apart. If you don't seal this very dry and vulnerable wood it won't last long anyway.

Good advice all around. I suggest PL400 or similar subfloor adhesive instead of construction adhesive. It stays pliable.
